# Why it is a good practise to use N prefix even though the characters themselves are ascii?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know N prefix is used for representing Unicode characters but I saw sql like this:

```
SELECT custid, country, region, city
FROM Sales.Customers
WHERE region = N'WA';
```

let's analyze different scenarios:

(input data is ascii characters)

**Scenario One:** region column uses varchar

clearly `WA` is standard ascii characters, and since region column's data are also ascii characters, so using `N'WA'` is redundant

**Scenario Two:** region column uses nvarchar

`WA` is standard ascii characters. using `N'WA'` is reasonable, because we want to convert ascii characters to Unicode characters and do the comparasion.

Another sql:

```
SELECT custid, country, region, city
FROM Sales.Customers
WHERE region = N'Wá';
```

and here comes another two scenarios:

(input data is unicode characters)

**Scenario Three**: region column uses nvarchar

because both of column's data and input data are unicode characters, using `N'Wá'` is redundant

**Scenario Four**: region column uses varchar

none of record will match, using `N'Wá'` is redundant

so for me, I think using `N` prefix only fits scenario two. but we need to have a look if underlying column use nvarchar or varchar, we can't just use N prefix everywhere

Comment: Also see https://sqlperformance.com/2013/04/t-sql-queries/implicit-conversion-costs

Answer (score 1):

**Senerio 1**, the rules for data type precedence will cause a column-side data type conversion and prevent index use.

In AdventureWorks, examine the plans and you'll see that the nvarchar parameter forces an index scan, where the varchar enables an index seek.

```
SELECT *
FROM Sales.Customer
WHERE AccountNumber = N'WA';
```

[image]
and

```
SELECT *
FROM Sales.Customer
WHERE AccountNumber = 'WA';
```

[image]

**Scenario 2** is fine either way, as the varchar parameter value will be the target of the data type conversion.

For this

```
SELECT custid, country, region, city
FROM Sales.Customers
WHERE region = N'Wá';
```

the using an nvarchar literal is required because the character `á` may not be available in the database collation, and then 'Wá' would evaluate to a varchar with a garbage character.

Comment: Adding that for scenario 1, the same query would seek if the column collation were Windows collation Latin1_General_CI_AS instead of a legacy SQL collation SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS. Regardless, I suggest one always match the column data type with literals or parameters. It's not that hard and will promote sargable expressions.

Comment: Yes.  There are a number of special cases implemented to prevent column-side conversions that the precedence rules would otherwise require, especially among numeric types.